# ItemsControl of a UserControl passing back ICommand to ViewModel MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have an 'ItemsViewModel' ViewModel which is bound to the 'ItemsView' View. Within the ViewModel I have full property List 'ItemsList' which is bound to an ItemsControls ItemsSource. The DataTemplate is then set to a UserControl called 'ItemControl'.

This works great, and within the UserControl I can bind to the public properties within my Model, and I'm assuming based on what I've read that this is the most appropriate way of doing this, but what I'm not sure on is how I can propagate back a button command to the ViewModel.

The way I have done it in the code below is to use 'FindAncestor', but this doesn't feel right.

`{Binding AddItemCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl, AncestorLevel=2}}">`

I have also read varying opinions on binding the whole UserControl to it's own ViewModel. For instance what if the UserControl now requires having 10 Buttons on it which makes it complex, and this argument was saying that UserControls should be simple, but why must they be? My use for UserControls is that I want to create a 'View' which I want to repeat 10, maybe 100, maybe 500 times, what if this view is complicated, with multiple buttons and types of Controls, does it warrant it's own ViewModel?

Any help or sources of information for this would be very much appreciated!

ViewModel:

```
public class ItemsViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public ICommand AddItemCommand { get; }

        public ItemsViewModel()
        {
            AddItemCommand = new CommandBase(AddItem);
        }

        private void AddItem(object obj)
        {
             *Code to run on button press*
        }

        private List<ItemList> itemsList;
        public List<ItemList> ItemsList
        {
            get
            {
                return itemsList;
            }
            set
            {
                itemsList = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ItemsList));
            }
        }
    }
```

Model:

```
    public class ItemList
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double Amount { get; set; }
    }

    public class ItemLists
    {
        public List<ItemList> itemLists { get; set; }

        public double totalAmount
        {
            get
            {
                double totalAmount = 0;

                foreach (var item in itemLists)
                {
                    totalAmount = totalAmount + item.Amount;
                }

                return totalAmount;
            }
        }
    }
```

View:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsList}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <usercontrol:ItemControl/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

UserControl:

```
<Button Command="{Binding AddItemCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl, AncestorLevel=2}}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text={Binding Name}/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text={Binding Amount}/>
    </Grid>
</Button>
```