# OnPropertyChanged of Model not updating UI

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am raising OnPropertyChanged on my model using a DispatchTimer in the ViewModel but the Model does not update in the UI, unless I reference the 'TimeSpan' properties of the Model.

The TextBlock within the view is updated every millisecond to show the TimeSpan increasing, but the TestUserControl doesn't update.

**ViewModel**

```
    public class TestViewModel: ViewModelBase
    {
        public DispatcherTimer _timer;

        public TestViewModel()
        {
            Test1 = new TestObject();
            Test1.Name = "TestName";
            Test1.DateTime = DateTime.Now;

            _timer = new DispatcherTimer(DispatcherPriority.Render);
            _timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1);
            _timer.Tick += (sender, args) =>
            {
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Test1));
            };
            _timer.Start();
        }

        private TestObject test1;
        public TestObject Test1
        {
           get
           {
               return test1;
           }
               set
           {
               test1 = value;
               OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Test1));
           } 
        }
    }
```

**Model**

```
    public class TestObject
    { 
        public string Name { get; set; }    
        public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }   
        public TimeSpan TimeSpan => DateTime.Now - DateTime;
    }
```

**View**

```
    <StackPanel>
        <userControls:TestUserControl DataContext="{Binding Test1}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Test1.TimeSpan}"/> //updating on UI
    </StackPanel>
```

**TestUserControl**

```
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/> //shows initial value
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding TimeSpan}"/> //shows initial value and does not update
    <StackPanel>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand Clemens, do you have a reference to help? Also why does Binding directly to the property of the object update? Is there a way I can Bind to DataContext.TimeSpan in the UserControl for it to work this way, without the need to implement INPC in the Model?

Comment: Just trying to follow! If you want to **bind to DataContext.TimeSpan in the UserControl** then what was your reasoning in putting `TimeSpan` property in `TestObject` instead of `DataContext`? I'm really trying to provide an answer that fits your question but I'm less sure now what that actually is. Sorry. If you're binding to a property, it's likely going to need to implement INPC due to the nature of binding.

Comment: @IV I have bound the UserControl to the Model because I then want to display a grid (or a more complex view) of all of the properties within the Model, and say I now want 10 UserControls I can create a new object for each one and just pass in a new instance of the model, I take it this is the right way to do this?
Or should I use an ItemsControl and then put what was in my UserControl XAML into it, and have a list of the Models in the TestViewModel?

Comment: Another option which works is creating a ViewModel to accompany the UserControl, and setting the DataContext of the UserControl to the ViewModel. Then within the ViewModel having test RandomObject Test element. This works when the DispatchTimer is in the UserControlVM and the UI elements are bound to each of the models properties such as Text = "{Binding Test.TimeSpan}".
However, I have read that this isn't advantageous, and have asked a question about it prior. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77063120/itemscontrol-of-a-usercontrol-passing-back-icommand-to-viewmodel-mvvm

Comment: Please provide a minimal, reproducible example. Right now it is not even clear what `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Test))` in the Tick handler is supposed to be doing. There is no Test property.

Comment: And quite obviously, for notifying a Binding like `Text="{Binding TimeSpan}"` the class that owns the TimeSpan property must fire a change notification, i.e. TestObject must implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: @Clemens - Apologies, of course it is meant to read 'OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Test1))'. 'Test1' being the RandomObject created in the constructor.

Comment: And as said before, `DataContext="{Binding Test1}"` will *not* result in an actual change of the DataContext when the value of the Test1 property has not changed, so no Bindings in the UserControl will be re-evaluated.

Comment: You should not use your code. First, your view model class does not need the DispatcherTimer. In your code the use of the Dispatcher is pointless. DtaeTime.Now is not precise at all. Right now, you are using a precision timer to query a coarse time source periodically to create a timer? Just use the time to increment value. You can configure the interval according to the required resolution.

Comment: You bind your TestUserControl to the TestObject.TimeSpan property, but this property never raises the PropertyChanged event. It should be obvious that this binding never updates. You must assign the new TimeSpan value from the Tick handler to the TestObject. Then in TestObject raise the PropertyChanged event.

Comment: @BionicCode I'm unsure what you mean from your last comment about it never updating the UI, because the TextBlock with Text bound to TestObject.TimeSpan DOES update the UI, whereas the UserControl doesn't. I'm also not Binding TestUserControl to the TestObject.TimeSpan, but setting the TestUserControl DataContext to TestObject. I'm also not concerned about the DispatchTimer, but just how I can refresh the UI to show the TimeSpan increasing, without the use of INPC on the Model, and without having a correspondent ViewModel for each UserControl.

Comment: Your TextBlock in View binds to the TestViewModel.Test1 property which is of type TestObject. Because in TestViewModel you raise PropertyChanged for Test1 from the Tick handler, the binding will update. It's a nested property path: Test1.TimeSpan. So, raising PropertyChanged for the outer property Test1 results in an update for the nested TestObject.TimeSpan. This makes sense as a change of the outer property Test1 means a new TesObject value, which likely results in a change of it's underlying nested TestObject.Timespan value too.

Comment: But because you set the DataContext explicitly for TestUserControl, the control's internals bind *directly* to TestObject.TimeSpan (no nested property path) as TestObject is the DataContext. This is not a nested property path for the binding! The internal bindings only react to PropertyChanged events raised by TestObject, what never happens. Not sure what you mean by "Model" because many people wrongfully use the term interchangeable with data model.

Comment: If TestObject is a class of the Model in terms of MVVM then you are *not allowed* to bind directly to it. It doesn't matter if the property path is nested/referenced via the view model class. The View is not allowed to reference it. And the View Model shouldn't expose it to the View in the first place. This means that your code is wrong. It's not INPC immerged by a class of the Model that violates MVVM, it's the reference from View to Model. In case TestObject is meant to be a data model (a View Model class), then it can serve as a binding source.

Comment: In that case it *must* implement INPC unless you want to create a memory leak. **Binding to an object that does not implement INPC will always create a memory leak (except the binding mode is OneTime or OneWayToSource)**. In your case the binding mode is OneWay --> memory leak. Don't writie ugly code only to hack around the implementation of INPC. In case TestObject is a Model class you must create a data model that you can legally use in the View. In this case the View Model would have to convert between the Model object (hidden from the View) and the View Model object (visible to the View).

Comment: ==> Never reference Model classes in the View (a data binding is a reference). Never bind to binding source that does not implement INPC (except the source is a DependencyObject that had implemented the source properties as dependency properties). Never follow the principle to have a dedicated View Model class for every control.

Comment: Right that explains a lot. I can't say I still understand why one Binding works but the other doesn't but your explanation of not exposing the Model (TestObject class in MVVM) makes sense, and not Binding to something that doesn't conform to INPC is clear, thank you so much. If I am trying to hack around not wanting to implement INPC, is it OK to then create a TestObjectViewModel to expose the fields of the Model to properties to bind to in my Model? I had read against doing this as well, but that or implementing INPC must be done for this to work right?

Comment: *"I had read against doing this as well,"* - I don't know how to say without sounding rude. You shouldn't follow anything you read on the internet without using your own CPU. Sadly MVVM is not well understood by most who feel like they must publish tutorials or teach others their "advices". It feels like >90% of MVVM related information is wrong at some point (e.g. no code -behind, handling controls/dialogs in the View Model, use Model types in the View, commands are mandatory, UI logic in the View Model etc.). That's really enjoying.

Comment: MVVM doesn't care about converting between model classes in order to pass them across boundaries (MVVM components). But MMVM card about the dependency of it's components and MVVM clearly rules that the View had no access to the Model. This is the main purpose of MVVM: decouple the UI and UI logic (View) from the real application (Model).

Comment: For this purpose MVVM introduces the View Model layer as sort of mediator: it actively reads data from the Model the make it passively available to the View for display/edit. The View Model also collects input/modified data and sends it actively back to the Model which processes it based on the business rules or persists the data. It is absolute normal to convert between data models. This is what MVVM dictates and you have to follow.

Comment: What is the alternatives? To use the Model class directly. But this violates MVVM, so it's not a valid alternative. Yes, thr conversion retires extra work. So what? Where you send data across boundaries you *always* have to do this conversation. For example you have to convert a local data model to JSON in order to pay it to the server. Then the server converts it to us own model type that it works with. The other "alternative" that doesn't qualify is too use View Model types in the Model because MVVM also forbids the reference of View Model classes/types in the Model.

Comment: You can be lazy and use either Model types in the View. or View Model types in the Model, but you just understand that this violates MVVM. Everybody who understands the MVVM design pattern will tell you that your design is wrong (in terms of MVVM). First understand the purpose and the decide if you want to sacrifice the benefits.

Comment: For example, when binding a View type to a Model type you lose the decoupling: when the Model type changes the View is broken and the View type and associated unit tests must be modified too. In addition, the View Model had to be modified too. That can get really ugly very fast. And time consuming. So better invest a fraction of this time in implementing the extra data types. You may get away with it in tiny applications. But it doesn't have to be an Enterprise application before it gets annoying.

Comment: For example, you change code in the Model after a while (e.g. to add/fix a feature) and everything stops working: several View Model classes are broken. But not annoyingly, the View is broken too - in multiple places (everywhere the type is referenced). You picked MVVM to avoid this in the first place, right? Now when you have a central point in the View Model that converts between the types, you have exactly one place that is broken: the type converter. I highly recommend to create the extra type in the View Model, especially as a beginner it helps to understand the pattern.

Comment: And if this question is in a professional context, you must do it unless you know the future and can guarantee that losing the decoupling won't hunt you (costing valuable and limited resources like personnel, time and money and die to the limitation likely impact other projects/tasks/timelines). There may be edge cases where the coupling doesn't matter. But you should know the risks (including the risk of a false assessment!). One is generally on the safe side when following a design pattern strictly as intended. And messing with architectural design patterns impacts the complete application.

Comment: Also, INPC is not part of the MVVM pattern definition. It's a WPF framework interface, that is used by the WPF binding engine. This interface just defined a PropertyChanged event, nothing else. There are tons of scenarios where you need s property change notification in the Model. You can implement such a notification explicitly like introducing a UsernameChanged event for the Username property or use a more generic event like PropertyChanged where you have to filter the event data to identify the property/changed data. The latter is highly extendible but ugly to handle, that's why WPF uses it

Comment: A framework must be highly extendible (client code) and the ugly handing is the trade-off, and is hidden inside the framework. Although in most scenarios a dedicated changed event for each property would make the most sense you can always implement INotifyPropertyChanged on *any* type. Like e.g. IDisposable or ICollection interfaces are not part of the MVVM definition and hence can't violate it. MVVM use about application architecture and not about particular interfaces. MVVM doesn't even data binding. It's just a technology to enable the View Model to passively "send" data to the View.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so whilst Im still looking for a way that is more appealing, a quick way to get this working is to make sure that whenever Test1 launches its ChangedMethod it triggers the Changed Methotds in its attributes.

So a you would rewrite TestObject like this

```
public class TestObject: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan Time => DateTime.Now - Date;

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new(propertyName));
    }

    public void FullUpdate()
    {
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Name));
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Date));
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Time));
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Option 1

---

```
public TestObject Test1
{
    get
    {
        return test1;
    }
    set
    {
        test1 = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
        test1.FullUpdate();
    }
}
```

Option 2

---

```
_timer.Tick += (sender, args) =>
{
    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Test1));
    Test1.FullUpdate();
};
```

This might not be very pleasant, but as I said im looking into other things as well. But this will get your example working